# netplan static and dynamic interfaces without default route for static?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I am trying to configure static and dynamic address with netplan on ubuntu server.
Problem is that while static interface gets route with metric 100 it still creates default one (0.0.0.0) with metric 0 which collides with my dynamic interface and I lose connection to internet.

Is there a way to tell netplan to stop adding default route (0.0.0.0) with metric 0 (or any metric) to the route?

Here is my config:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        route-metric: 0

    enp0s8:
       dhcp4: false
       dhcp4-overrides:
           use-routes: false
       addresses: [192.168.200.1/24]
       gateway4: 192.168.200.1
       nameservers:
           addresses: [8.8.8.8]
       routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 192.168.200.1
         metric: 100

  version: 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Removing gateway line worked for me:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        route-metric: 0

    enp0s8:
       dhcp4: false
       dhcp4-overrides:
           use-routes: false
       addresses: [192.168.200.1/24]
       # ------------ COMMENT THIS LINE ---------- gateway4: 192.168.200.1
       nameservers:
           addresses: [8.8.8.8]
       routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 192.168.200.1
         metric: 100

  version: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61474457/11902589) - Removing the following lines works as well:

```
       dhcp4-overrides:
         use-routes: false
       gateway4: 192.168.200.1
```

No need to specify `dhcp4-overrides` as this is a static route.